# Dependence of scattering amplitudes on Mandelstam variables

Tags: feynman-diagrams, differentiation

It is well-known that scattering amplitudes in QFT are tensors, hence e.g. scalar amplitudes /written in momentum space/ depend only on the Mandelstam variables of the external momenta, involved in the scattering. This allows us to claim that
$$A_n(\mathbf{p}_1, \dots, \mathbf{p}_n) = A_n(\{s_{ij}\}),$$
where $s_{ij} := \mathbf{p}_i \cdot \mathbf{p}_j$ (or equivalently $s_{ij} = (\mathbf{p}_i + \mathbf{p}_j)^2$)...

My question is how do we calculate derivatives of the kind $\frac{\partial}{\partial s} A_n$? I suppose we can write something along the line of:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial s} A_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\partial \mathbf{p}_k}{\partial s}\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{p}_k} A_n,$$
however, what exactly is $\partial \mathbf{p}_k / \partial s$? Is it the same as $\frac{1}{\partial s / \partial \mathbf{p}_k}$?

Furthermore, how do we determine which Madelstam variables to take as independent? (It is clear that the number of degrees of freedom of $\{ \mathbf{p}_i \} : \mathbf{p}_1 + \cdots + \mathbf{p}_n = 0$ is $(n-1)D$, while the degrees of freedom of the Mandelstam varaibles is $\binom{n+1}{2}$, so not all of them are mutually independent...)